# Replacing for loop by sql

Tags: sql

I have SQL for example

`show tables from mydb;`

It shows the list of table

```
|table1|
|table2|
|table3|
```

Then,I use sql sentence for each table.
such as  "show full columns from table1 ;"

```
+----------+--------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field    | Type   | Collation | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+----------+--------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| id       | bigint | NULL      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| user_id  | bigint | NULL      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| group_id | int    | NULL      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+----------+--------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

So in this case I can use programming language such as .(this is not correct code just showing the flow)

```
tables = "show tables from mydb;"
for t in tables:
    cmd.execute("show full columns from {t} ;")
```

However is it possible to do this in sql only?

Comment: Please specify the DB server - MS SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ... Probably the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` approach, suggested by @gotqn will work in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL you can use the system view -  [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html).

It contains table name and column name (and other details). No loop is require and you can easily filter by other information, too.

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

If you are using Microsoft SQL Server, you can use the above command